# Datediff returning days not years Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a column stored as the date/time data type upon which I wan't to calculate age in years.  I'm using the `DateDiff` function in Access 2007.

```
SELECT Visits.ID, Visits.DOB, DateDiff("y",[DOB],[date]) AS age
FROM Visits;
```

As an aside to this question, I tried to use [date] to select the current date whenever the query is ran, but it just gave me a prompt to type in the date, it didn't grab it automatically.

DOB is the date of birth for each record.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question use `DATE()` instead of [Date], so you would end up with `DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Date())`

Comment: You will need to account for days & months, e.g. that expression would return 0 for someone born this year as it wont account for the period beyond the actual birthday

Comment: Yes, Access thinks `[date]` is a field. The square brackets indicate fields and allow to use reserved words like `[SELECT]` or function names as `[DateDiff]` as field names.

Comment: all helpful, QaD solutions.  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify "yyyy" for the interval argument, instead of "y". "yyyy" is the year, "y" is the day of year.

Comment: thanks, will accept in five minutes when it lets me.  what say you about using today's date instead of having to type the date in?

Comment: Beware! `DateDiff("yyyy", #2010-12-31#, #2011-01-01#)` will return 1 even though the difference is just one day!

Comment: Yes, it calculates `Year(date2) - Year(date1)`.